# Unable to understand Mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

I am going through a PHP Script and the code/syntax I saw is totally new to me. Can anyone tell me in detail what actually its about?

```
$products = $this->db->select(
    array(
        'table'=>'product_categories pc, product_price pp, alias a, products p 
                    LEFT JOIN product_images pi 
                    ON 
                    pi.product_id = p.id ',
        'fields'=>'*',
        'condition'=>"pc.category_id='" . $row['id'] . "' 
                        AND 
                    pc.product_id = p.id 
                        AND 
                    pp.product_id = p.id  
                        AND 
                    a.table_id = p.id 
                        AND 
                    a.table_name = 'products'", 
        'order'=>'p.ordr ASC'));
```

Comment: You are probably using some kind of framework that use a data base abstraction of some sort. So instead of writing queries you can build queries like the above. If you check where $this->db is set and follow that trail back to see what "db" in this sense actually is, then you should be able to find out what you are dealing with / find more docs online.

Comment: Is this a Laravel framework code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is the database selector receives an array.

- In the `$array['table']` part are all the table and join instructions
- In the `$array['fields']` part are the fields from the array that are in need of selecting
- In the `$array['condition']` are all the requirements the rows must meet to be included in the selecton.
- And in the `$array['order']` part how to order

Personally I think this is a very very messy way to do this. This is basically just a very bad. There is no use of prepared statements, and its more cumbersome than the actual query itself

```
SELECT * FROM product_categories pc, product_price pp, alias a, products p 
                LEFT JOIN product_images pi 
                ON 
                pi.product_id = p.id 
    WHERE pc.category_id=:myid
                    AND 
                pc.product_id = p.id 
                    AND 
                pp.product_id = p.id  
                    AND 
                a.table_id = p.id 
                    AND 
                a.table_name = 'products' 
    ORDER BY p.ordr ASC
```

A tip for you next time, clean up the code like I did with your tidbit, usually a mess will become clear when its idented. It becomes easier to see what happens where.

Also, I suggest reading up on [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)